# Can i get the height and width of an Image which is stored on my device

Tags: android

I need to get the height and width of an Image which is stored on my Android Device. I already know how to get the file(image), I just need some code how to get the height and width from that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can.

you can try this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("your image path");
int width =  bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();
```

note: You should have permission to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the dimensions of the image but not the decoded image itself, you can use `BitmapFactory.Options` with `inJustDecodeBounds = true` to do so:

```
BitmapFactory.Options decodeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
decodeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true; 
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, decodeOptions);
//decodeOptions.outWidth and decodeOptions.outHeight now contain the image dimensions
```

This way the decode function will return null but set the out variables of the options object. This saves both CPU and memory which can be advantageous if you are processing lots of images at once.